# LibreOffice Writer: Insert a list of names, one per page

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to print certificates for people who have taken a course. Since it's a large number of people, it would be rather tedious to copy-and-paste all those names into a document, so I'd like to automate that process.

Here's what I have:

- a dummy certificate in the form of a writer .odt document ("[NAME] has successfully taken part in course X.")
- a list with the names of all participants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenOffice (which functions identically here) has a [Form Letter Guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Creating_a_form_letter), or LibreOffice has a [Wizard to walk you through this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Mail_Merge_Wizard). Choose **Tools** | **Mail Merge Wizard** | Click the **Mail Merge icon** on the Table Data bar to begin it. Here's a one minute [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prZJ4w-q9AA) on the latter method.

Comment: The video was particularly helpful. Thank you! That saved me large amounts of valuable lifetime! :)